# What is the official name of the number in a Gerrit review url

Tags: git, gerrit

I have been using `Git/Gerrit` for about 9 months and I still don't know the
answer to this question.  (c.f. [Gerrit Documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/intro-gerrit-walkthrough.html)  )

In `Gerrit`, when a change is pushed for review, there will be an URL about the change with an embedded number.  For example:

```
http://gerrithost:8080/68
```

What is the official name of this number? (`68` in the above example).  This number is an important concept when discussing the Gerrit workflow.

On the Gerrit UI, this number may also shown on the upper left-hand conner.  Something like:

```
Change 68 - Merged
```

The number is a small integer that seems to increase monotonically when pushes are submitted to the Gerrit server.

This number should NOT be confused with "Change-Id" because the latter is a long hash (prefixed by the letter `I`) used to identify multiple related pushes (created with one `commit` followed by one or more `commit --amend`) into one "Change" (which can have one or more "Patch-Set") . E.g:

```
Change-Id: Ic8aaa0728a43936cd4c6e1ed590e01ba8f0fbf5b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "**change number**" which is sometimes referenced in the documentation as "legacy ID number", "legacy numerical id" or "legacy numeric change ID".

Comment: Thanks!  I posted a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49264185/official-documentation-about-gerrit-change-number